# How does load balancing work for a coreOS cluster?

Tags: load-balancing, cluster, haproxy, coreos

Preface: I don't know much about load balancing.

Say I have a few virtual machines on a cloud service like Amazon, running a few instances of coreOS each.

How exactly does load balancing work in this scenario? I imagine that normally there is one machine running linux with HAProxy installed, and that is the IP that's hooked up to your domain name and whatever else.

CoreOS however has Fleet, which is supposed to distribute tasks between cluster nodes. Does this change the dynamic of load balancing?

Answer (score 1):

Fleet does not directly interact with load balancers.  You could use a "presence" container as described in the example at https://coreos.com/docs/launching-containers/launching/fleet-example-deployment/ to manage an ELB.